# Hartshorne III.theorem.7.11

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[image]

I can’t understand definition of $\mathfrak{m}$.

In this case, is $A$ local ring？

Comment: No, $A$ is the section ring/coordinate ring of the open affine $U \subset P$, so $\mathfrak m$ is just the maximal ideal corresponding to some closed point of $X$ which lies in $U$ (treated as a point of $U$, not a point of $X\cap U$).

Comment: @TabesBridges looks like an answer to me! Would you care to record it below?

Comment: Despite the length of the screenshot, I suppose that is pretty much all there is to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $A$ is not a local ring; it is the section ring/coordinate ring of the open affine $U\subset P$, so $\mathfrak m$ is just the maximal ideal corresponding to some closed point of $X$ which lies in $U$ (treated as a point of $U$, not a point of $X\subset U$).

Comment: Sorry for stray from this content, what does it mean “the exterior powers of matrix $||c_{ij}||$ give an isomorphism of Kozsul complex.”?

Comment: The terms of the Koszul resolution of an ideal come from taking exterior powers of the ideal (actually this works for any $R$ module with a map to $R$). So at the first step (the module itself) the change of basis matrix gives an isomorphism $f:M \to M$ a.k.a. $\wedge^1 M \to \wedge^1 M$, and you get other associated isomorphisms $\wedge^k M \to \wedge^k M$ by taking exterior powers of the matrix for $f$.

Comment: How to induce $\wedge^k M\to \wedge^k M$ by f. Could you tell me this definition.

Comment: I would suggest consulting your favorite textbook on multilinear algebra for that.

Comment: Thank you very much.